# Capture filter filter with tcpdump/tshark

Tags: packet-capture

I'd like to filter ip messages which are constructed as follow (see picture below):

1. GRE on top of IP
2. GRE contains IP with UDP on port 1234 (in the picture below port 80).

How can I filter such messages?

[image]

PS operating system is windows based

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure by what you mean with "on top" of GRE so I'll include both.

1. If you are trying to capture packets going to and from a GRE and you know the interface for the GRE tunnel you can do `tcpdump -i GRE_INTERFACE host IP` to show all traffic going to and from "IP", if you just want traffic going to it change host to dst. To get just UDP traffic on port 1234 `tcpdump -i GRE_INTERFACE host IP and udp and port 1234`
2. If you are trying to capture GRE packets themselves you can do `tcpdump -i any proto gre`, if you have too much GRE traffic and want to see it by the specific tunnel do `tcpdump -i any proto gre and host IP_OF_GRE_TUNNEL_REMOTE`

I hope this helps

Comment: I've clarified my question by adding example packet capture